# Creating a test function for another function in python

Tags: python, debugging, testing

So my assignment is to write a test function for the two functions in the given code. I do not understand the concept of pass/fail statements for this and I need some guidance. I am going to post the code below. I am not asking for answers since this is hw. I need an explanation of logic.

```
 #######################################################################
 ## problem 1 of 2.
 #######################################################################
 # There is a problem with the is_reverse_of function below.
 # Assignment 1:
 # 1.1. Develop a suite of tests to properly test the function.
 # 1.2. Debug this faulty function to locate and correct the problem.

def is_reverse_of( st1, st2 ):
       """
    is_reverse_of : String String -> Boolean
    is_reverse_of tells if one string is the reverse of another.
    preconditions: st1 and st2 are character strings.
    """
    if len( st1 ) != len( st2 ):
        return False
    i = 0
    j = len( st2 )
    while j > 0:
        if st1[i] != st2[j]:
            return False
        i += 1
        j -= 1

    return True

def test_is_reverse_of():
    """
    a suite of pass/fail test cases to validate that is_reverse_of works.
    """
    # Complete this test function.
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    test_is_reverse_of()
```

Comment: You're going to get a better response if you post the code that you have having issues with and nothing else. Especially over copying an entire homework assignment verbatum. See [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on how to create minimal examples.

Comment: Do you want actual Python unit testing or just a quick and dirty solution? Python has its own unittest module, but that might be outside the scope of your assignment?

Comment: quick and dirty solution. utilizing a series of print statements.(I believe that is how pass/fail works).

Answer (score 0):

You might be misunderstanding what the `pass` keyword is doing there. `pass` is a Python keyword that basically equates to a blank line. You use it when you have a section of code that you want 'passed' when called. The `pass` is in the code right now simply so that it can be interpreted and not give an error.

What this assignment is asking for at this level I think is simply a list of 'testcases'.

Think of several ways a reverse_string function might fail. What if the length is 0? What if the length is very large? What if it has numbers? What if it mixes cases? What if you don't input strings? What if the strings are exactly the same? What if the strings aren't the same length? And so on.

So you end up with code like:

```
if (is_reverse_of("food","doof") != True):
    print("Func is wrong!")
```

Comment: So a test function just calls to see if it works, as well as check for other possible failures basically?

Comment: And I believe the error in reverse string is that it should be `j =  len( st2 )- 1`

Comment: That is what 'unit testing' is. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing has more information on it.

Comment: @darksoulsfan : Yes. You want to ensure that the function behaves properly both with good data (strings that are actually reverses of each other) and bad / weird data, as Eugene mentions. Often the bad data tests outnumber the good ones.

Comment: @darksoulsfan : FWIW, the given `is_reverse_of()` is a reasonable example function for learning how to write tests. But a real program would (probably) use `st1 == st2[::-1]` which is much more succinct. And generally quite a bit faster. The looping method is ok if mismatches occur early, but it's rather slow if they don't.

Comment: My only confusion is whether to use print statements or conditionals.